# Swift initializer inheritance

Tags: swift, initialization

Can you tell me why the superclass initializer gets called because I never call it from the initializer in subclass ?

Regarding the two step process of the initialization, I thought that the compiler would throw an error because I didn't call `super.init()` actually

```
class Superclass {
    var a: Int

    init() {
        self.a = 1
    }
}

class Subclass: Superclass {
    var b: Int

    override init() {
        self.b = 2
    }
}

var subclass = Subclass()
print(subclass.b)
// Print 2
print(subclass.a)
// Print 1 => How is it possible as I never call super.init() ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler [can synthesise a call](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bef9a49af96a88c42fa8711a3c39ef6738b0a49e/lib/Sema/TypeCheckStmt.cpp#L1579) to `super.init()` in a designated initialiser if you don't make the call yourself. So in your case the compiler effectively transforms your code to:

```
class Superclass {
  var a: Int

  init() {
    self.a = 1
  }
}

class Subclass : Superclass {
  var b: Int

  override init() {
    self.b = 2
    super.init() // synthesised by the compiler
  }
}
```

This also applies to cases where you're not overriding the superclass' `init()`:

```
class Subclass : Superclass {
  var b: Int

  init(b: Int) {
    self.b = b
    super.init() // also synthesised by the compiler (try removing)
  }
}
```

Note that this synthesis comes with some restrictions, it only applies when:

1. The superclass has one and only one *designated* initialiser
2. This designated initialiser doesn't have any parameters, i.e `init()`

In all other cases you need to call `super.init` yourself.